# Access JSON object to get Resource Bundle key/value pair

Tags: javascript, json

I know how to access key value pair from JSON object but in my case, the resource bundle keys are mapped to values.

e.g.

```
var json = {"label.name.first":"foo","label.name.second":"bar"};
```

Here **json.label.name.first** doesn't give me "foo".

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: could you paste your original json here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to using the period character (`.`) in the key name, you need to use the `[]` notation to access its value.

```
console.log( json['label.name.first'] );
```

Additionally, you have a JavaScript object, not JSON.

---

The difference between a JavaScript object or JSON is that JSON is always a string. Secondly, JavaScript objects don't require the same quote standards on the key names.

If you just consider the string below, then yes it can be considred JSON (this is why if you paste it into a JSON parser, it tells you it's valid JSON):

```
{"label.name.first":"foo","label.name.second":"bar"}
```

However, if you assign that directly to a JavaScript variable then you have a JavaScript object literal, not JSON. This is because JSON is also a valid JavaScript object/array literal when it is not contained in a string:

```
var obj = {"label.name.first":"foo","label.name.second":"bar"};
```

If you were to use it as a string, then it is JSON:

```
var json = '{"label.name.first":"foo","label.name.second":"bar"}';
// json is a string, so it's JSON
var obj = JSON.parse(json); // parse the JSON into an object
```

The confusion is quote common because the JSON format is very similar to the format of JavaScript object and array literals.

Comment: Confused! What's not JSON?  And why?  Since JSONlint likes that object.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Where does this distinction come from?  I can't see it in json.org or RFC7159.  I would have thought that being in a string just means it's serialised, like when you have XML in a JavaScript string as opposed to in a file.

Comment: JSON is language agnostic so I haven't looked but there probably won't be references to JavaScript usage in the JSON spec. The JSON format just happens to be valid JavaScript if you assign it to a variable or pass it to a function without wrapping quotes, but if you do that then you wouldn't consider a variable/argument to contain JSON unless it's a string that you have to parse.

Comment: I understand.  Thanks.  You can paste JSON directly into JavaScript, without quotes, and if you do, that's not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
json["label.name.first"]
```

However, I think you are misunderstanding the `.` notation.

And BTW your json isn't a JSON, it is a javascript object and not its notation.

Answer (score 1):

It's `json["label.name.first"]` that would get you `"foo"`.  Since your property's name contains characters that cannot be used in variable names.

If you're expecting to access these properties using the syntax `json.label.name.first` then your JSON needs to be:

```
var json = {
    "label":{
         "name":{
             "first":"foo",
             "second":"bar"
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not right way to create object, you should create one like this.

```
var json={"label":{"name":{"first":"foo","second":"bar"}}};
```

it will also work as json string

Comment: It's a perfectly legititmate way to create an object. But you're right that your methodology would let the OP access the value in the way he tried.